# Adding query string to Ajax url call

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I wanna kn is it possible to pass query string along with URL when we call on Jquery Ajax;

Example :

```
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "index.php?task=addNewInfo",
           data: $('#regForm').serialize(),
           dataType: "json",
              .....
      });
```

So does the query string from the param task works fine? or we need to do it the other way?
Thank you.

Comment: You're using POST. your serialized data is the... "query string"... or more accurately, the parameters you're sending. It only becomes a query string if you're using GET.

Comment: It seems you are accessing **task** through $_GET and other data through $_POST. You should send the task in the data instead of querystring.

Comment: Yes. Why not just try it and see.

Comment: @GregPettit — The query string component of the URL is the query string no matter what HTTP verb is used for the request.

Comment: Could you please unaccept my answer?

Comment: Y'know sometimes you look back at old code or old comments, @Quentin and wonder what you were thinking? You prompted me to do just that about my own comment. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send the task in the data parameter

```
data:"task=addNewInfo&" + $('#regForm').serialize()
```

This is for using POST method.
If you want to use GET method then Arun's solution will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following will work fine

```
url : "index.php?task=addNewInfo&" + $('#regForm').serialize()
```

But why do you want to pass the form values as query params? The post request will pass the values as request params anyway. These params will be sent via the request body which is why you are using `POST` request type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. query-string and request body are 2 different things in HTTP requests.
jQuery wrap the data in the query-string for GET requests, which is probably the source of confusion

- GET request: the body (or payload) is empty, only the url holds data.
- POST request: fill the body as you like, either with url-encoding like you did, or with json-encoding