# ajaxSubmit not posting to full url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

what am trying to do is submit a form using `ajaxSubmit` as follow :

```
$("#login").ajaxSubmit({
    url: "index.php?page=login", 
    type: 'post', 
    success: function(responseText){
        alert(responseText);
    }
});
```

but instead of posting the data to `index.php?page=login` it post it to `index.php` which result in wrong response , how I supposed to fix that?

Comment: A normal POST request shouldn't include a query string.

Comment: I know you can do this with ASP.Net, but can you access both GET and POST data with PHP?

Comment: I am afraid the portion before the ? is the actual endpoint and if you want to achieve what you want, i guess you need to write a condition to check if the request has a query parameter "page" which equals "login".

Comment: You're mixing up the `url` part with the `data` part. And as mentioned before, a `POST` shouldn't have a `querystring`.

Answer (score 1):

A normal POST request shouldn't include a query string. If you need pass some data, you have to use the "data" option.

```
data: { page: 'login' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post, I think it will help you do what you're looking for. Basically you can't add the query string to the url, but you can add it to the data

[Adding query string to Ajax url call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544895/adding-query-string-to-ajax-url-call)

Answer (score 0):

Use serialize: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serialize.asp

$("#login").submit(function() {
        var url = "path/to/your/index.php";

```
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#login").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data);
           }
         });

    return false; 
});
```